# Editor Window - How to create this?

Tags: unity

I am trying to create this in my editor window but not sure how. Basically a drop down arrow, next to a C# icon, next to a toggle, next to a Label with a cog at the end [image]

Comment: What exactly do you want? This is C# script and those are public / Serializable fields.

Comment: Ignore the variables. I just need those stuff I mentioned in my post. I am trying to create a box like that